# cannot load html file when using angularjs with webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-router

I'm webpack beginner.

I want to build angular project with webpack but when I set route with angular-ui-router ( like '/home' ), 'home' page was empty. Nothing loaded.

I use 'raw-loader' of webpack to load html files but didn't work ..

Please give me little help. I feel desperate :(

[project repo](https://github.com/hagfish1210/webpack-with-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are missing `<ui-view><ui-view>` in you index.html

Comment: oh that was stupid mistake. thanks for the answer !
but same result yet..

( change ng-view to ui-view right away. )